# Activar un option específico por su ID

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio:

> Al dar clic en un botón ejecute un JavaScript añadiendo el `selected` a un option específico por ID.

El problema es con el JavaScript no sé cómo es la sintaxis correcta. Encontré que se puede hacer de la siguiente manera: `document.getElementById("datos_select").selectedIndex = 1;` solo que éste lo ordena de por index iniciando de cero (0), yo lo quiero poner el `selected` según el `value,` el cual uno de ellos sera enviado al dar clic en el botón.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```js
Select_orden = function(id) {
  document.getElementById("datos_select").selectedIndex = id;

}
```

```html
<h4>Activar option del select segun boton </h4>
<button type="button" onclick="Select_orden('0')" name="button">ordenar Select 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Select_orden('1')" name="button">ordenar Select 2</button>

<select name="datos_select" id="datos_select">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hola César, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Comment: Y no te olvides de marcar como aceptada la respuesta que mejor te funcione. Eso te dará puntos y ayudará a marcar la publicación como completada :)

Answer (score 0):

primero que nada debes pasar el valor(value) a una funcion que recibira este parametro con ello mediante el ID del select establecemos el value del mismo algo asi:

```
<h4>Cambio de valores en Select </h4>
<button type="button" onclick="Select_orden('1')" name="button">ordenar Select 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Select_orden('2')" name="button">ordenar Select 2</button>

<select  name="datos_select" id="datos_select" >
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
<script>
function Select_orden(valor){
document.getElementById('datos_select').value=valor;
}
</script>
```

Si te fijas establesco o defino el id del select en:

```
('datos_select')
```

y para definir el valor y dar el selected x defecto uso el value:

```
value=valor
```

donde valor es el parametro enviado previamente a la funcion **Select_orden**

espero te sirva y suerte ..!!

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en que las etiquetas `<option>` no tienen el id, sino el valor.

Y creo que está es una forma más sencilla de hacer un `selected` a una opción.

```js
Select_orden = function(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).selected = "true";

}
```

```html
<h4>Cambio de valores en Select </h4>
<button type="button" onclick="Select_orden('1')" name="button">ordenar Select 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Select_orden('2')" name="button">ordenar Select 2</button>

<select name="datos_select" id="datos_select">
  <option id="1" value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option id="2" value="2">Valor 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Por favor, no publiques múltiples respuestas con información nueva. Si quieres añadir más detalles siempre puedes darle a editar la publicación y añadir los nuevos datos. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Perdona la anterior fue por que se me fue el dedo y se publicó sin querer, pero ya la eliminé, está es la respuesta que doy peró la anterior fué fallo mío.

Comment: pero no es necesario la elimines, basta con que le des editar y corrige todo lo necesario; te lo digo por que por ejemplo para los usuarios de 10000 puntos o mas si no es visible tu anterior respuesta aunque la borraste

Comment: @shadow oh! vale me lo apunto para la próxima, ¡Gracias por la información!